# Trying to select an option from the dropdown in Selenium web automation -error- "ElementNotInteractableException: could not be scrolled into view"

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

```
package com.web.automation;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class dropDown {
WebDriver driver;
    @BeforeMethod
    public void site() throws InterruptedException{
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "geckodriver");
        driver =  new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.amazon.com/");
        }
    
        @AfterMethod
        public void close(){
            driver.close();
            }
        @Test
        public void register() throws InterruptedException{
        Select s = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='searchDropdownBox']")));
        s.selectByValue("search-alias=alexa-skills");
        }
}
```

Code Explanation:

I am trying to automate [www.amazon.com](http://www.amazon.com) web page. There is drop down list called "All" in the home page itself. if we click the All dropdown menu there will be different option to choose. Using Selenium automation I am trying to click the drop down and select one of the option.

```
Select s = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='searchDropdownBox']")));
s.selectByValue("search-alias=alexa-skills");
```

Error:

```
FAILED: register
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: Element <option> could not be scrolled into view
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
```

Comment: <select aria-describedby="searchDropdownDescription" class="nav-search-dropdown searchSelect" data-nav-digest="MBCJnu8VgK5vcuYV9qp6ymW2rgc=" data-nav-selected="0" id="searchDropdownBox" name="url" style="display: block; top: 2.5px;" tabindex="0" title="Search in">
        <option selected="selected" value="search-alias=aps">All Departments</option>
        <option value="search-alias=audible">Audible Books &amp; Originals</option>

Comment: The above text is the element. Due to the text limitation I am not able to add the whole html element

Comment: Try adding explicit wait using ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElement .

Answer (score 0):

To select the option with text as `Books` from the dropdown you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *cssSelector* and `selectByVisibleText()`:

  ```
  new Select(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("select#searchDropdownBox")))).selectByVisibleText("Books");
  ```
- Using *xpath* and `selectByValue()`:

  ```
  new Select(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//select[@id='searchDropdownBox']")))).selectByValue("search-alias=stripbooks-intl-ship");
  ```

Comment: Great! This will be helpful to me in the future. But I think I have located the element of search box instead of drop down button. because drop down is div element. <div class="nav-search-scope nav-sprite" style="background: rgb(204, 136, 136); border: 2px solid red;">
    <div class="nav-search-facade" data-value="search-alias=aps">
      <span class="nav-search-label" style="width: auto;">All</span>
      <i class="nav-icon"></i>
    </div>

Comment: Since I am following a tutorial, I believe soon I will find the solution to select the drop down option for div tag, because the above code I mentioned will work for "select" tag. Thanks for your response @DebanjanB.

Comment: @KrishnaveniRaju Aren't you trying to interact with the same `<select>` tag as per the xpath in your code trials `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='searchDropdownBox']"))`?