# Selenium unable to find the element which is present on the html

Tags: java, html, selenium-webdriver

1. I can manually inspect and get the xpath of the element.
2. when I get the xpath of that element, it says 1 of 1.  I can create a unique Xpath for the element.
3. But the selenium cannot find it.

I'm using Waits.  So, there is no problem of skipping an element.  But, There is also not any iframe in html.  still The selenium cannot able to find the element which I've create the Xpath for.  I provided a screen shot of that issue.[image: screenshot of my issue]

This is the code for that:

```
webEssentials.waitTillElementIsAvailableInDOM(By.xpath("//select[@name='senderId']"));
webEssentials.waitTillElementIsClickable(selectSenderId);
WebElement element = webEssentials.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@name='senderId']"));
        Select select = new Select(element);
        select.selectByIndex(0);

        webEssentials.waitTillElementIsVisible(templateZoho).
                waitTillElementIsClickable(templateZoho);
        WebElement element1 = webEssentials.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@name='template']"));
        Select select1 = new Select(element1);
        select1.selectByIndex(0);
```

[1]: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1rvqESd2SE4cUqGyY7FK-8brI_q_F-6am?usp=sharing   **This Link having the error log of what I'm getting after the selenium cannot find the element**

Comment: Can you share the URL of the application if it is public?

Comment: Actually, it is private shawn

Comment: Have you checked if the "@name" attribute is always present when "select" is rendered? From my experience the "@name" attribute is not reliable when identifying elements with angular. Maybe try with "ng-reflect-name".

Comment: In your error log it's trying to find element "//iframe[@role='presentation']". As you said if you don't have iframe in your page, may be you should to remove the step in your code where searching this element

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is an [Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73241154/7429447) element. To select one of the [select-options](/questions/tagged/select-options) from a [html-select](/questions/tagged/html-select) tag you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the [*`elementToBeClickable()`*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63301869/7429447) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *name*:

  ```
  WebElement element = new Select(new WebDriverWait(webEssentials.driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.name("senderId"))));
  ```
- Using *cssSelector*:

  ```
  WebElement element = new Select(new WebDriverWait(webEssentials.driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("select[name='senderId']"))));
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  WebElement element = new Select(new WebDriverWait(webEssentials.driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//select[@name='senderId']"))));
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to select an option from a dropdown through Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49772710/how-to-select-an-option-from-a-dropdown-through-selenium-webdriver/49777340#49777340)
- [Trying to select an option from the dropdown in Selenium web automation -error- "ElementNotInteractableException: could not be scrolled into view"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63854405/trying-to-select-an-option-from-the-dropdown-in-selenium-web-automation-error/63855001#63855001)
- [How to retrieve the value of options from a select drop-down using Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56684736/how-to-retrieve-the-value-of-options-from-a-select-drop-down-using-selenium/56685051#56685051)

Comment: Actually I'm using the waits in another method. 
webEssentials.waitTillElementIsAvailableInDOM(By.xpath("//select[@name='senderId']"));
        webEssentials.waitTillElementIsClickable(selectSenderId);

 Which will do its work before this code that I mentioned.

Comment: What will you suggest undected Selenium?

I also used this waits in the same method, it is failing in the waits itself.  Because, it is waiting for certain time period.  But it cannot find the element, so it is failing.

Comment: How is `waitTillElementIsAvailableInDOM()` and `waitTillElementIsClickable()` defined? I don't see them in your code trials. Not even the error. What error do you see?

Comment: Hello undetected Selenium, I now added the error log of what I'm getting above.  Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your xpath is correct. Then can you please use *javaScriptExecutOr* method to lcik the lement. Below is the sample code: Also pleas refer [link](https://medium.com/@biswasarpita/javascriptexecutor-in-selenium-webdriver-with-example-4fe356f41b62)

 Can you please check also-> whether there is any frame available, then you need to switch to that frame first.

```
 driver.switchTo().frame("frame id");

 WebElement ele= driver.findElement(By.xpath(""));        
 js.executeScript(“arguments[0].click();”, ele);
```